# Cant publish Application in Azure using the same account IN VS 2019

Tags: c#, angular, azure, visual-studio-code

Hi I am trying to publish an Angular application in Azure with VS CODE
but I'm receiving a scope invalid error

What I have used is the same account I'm using in VS-2019 in which I succeeded but for some reason is not working in Visual Studio Code

Any idea why?

Note: I have already succeeded in deploying multiple webapi application in azure using Visual Studio 2019. Now when im using the same account in VS CODE I'm receiving a  'does not have authorization to perform action...' error

Comment: could you have atleast point the reason why after  downvoting?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the error? Maybe also the steps you are doing to publish the app?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/javascript/tutorial-vscode-azure-app-service-node-01) doc for detailed steps on deploying an App Service on Azure through VS Code. I just tried it and was able to publish my webapp successfully.

If you still face issues, please post the exact error message with as much detail and screenshots, if any, and we can troubleshoot it further.